# Radio button toggle switch to change stylesheets

Tags: css, radio-button, toggle

I made 2 stylesheets on my site (day and night, because i find it hard to read full white background style in pitch black room at night)

I found styled toggle switches and I wish to use them on the css switcher.

```
<div class="switch switch-blue">
<input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view2" value="week2" id="week2" checked>
<label for="week2" class="switch-label switch-label-off">Week</label>
<input type="radio" class="switch-input" name="view2" value="month2" id="month2">
<label for="month2" class="switch-label switch-label-on">Month</label>
<span class="switch-selection"></span>
</div>
```

if I load both my stylesheets in the document

```
<a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('default'); return false;">style 1</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('alternate 1'); return false;">style 2</a>
```

how do I make the radio button to switch between these two?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to add (for example) `onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('default');"` to your `<input type="radio">`. Note that you shouldn't use `return false;` in this case, because it will prevent the radio from having the selected appearance.